# Are regression models from different packages (strucchange and forecast) the same?

Tags: r, regression, breakpoints, forecasting

I'm trying to use both forecasting and change point detection on a regression model, i.e. I want to see the forecasts of the regression model (package forecast) and run an "online" change point detection monitor on new data (package strucchange) to see if it actually behaves as expected.

The question is whether the regression models from the two packages are so similar that the monitor would detect it if the new data deviates from the forecasts?

The monitor from package strucchange detects if the structure of a regression model fitted to the historic period stops explaining new data.

I'm a little bit confused as to whether this is equivalent to deviating significantly from the forecasts from the same regression model fitted to the same set of observations.

Can anybody help me clear this up?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this question with not data or code, requesting general statistical advice, is more appropriate for CV.com.

Comment: It is about R. I guess I could try to read the source code and see if the two packages implement regression models in the same way, but I thought I would try asking here first. I agree that the theoretical question whether a structural change in a regression model is the same as deviation from a forecast may be for another forum, but I want to know it for these two specific R packages.